# Understanding lambda calculus through translation into Python?

Tags: python, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to understand how lambda calculus works and how to simplify or expand different statements.

Given the example statement `(λz.z) (λy.y y) (λx.x a)` am I translating and simplifying this statement correctly?

---

Here's my solution:

```
# (λz.z) (λy.y y) (λx.x a) 
#    F      G        H
# statement translates to -> F( G( H(x) ) )

f = lambda z: z
g = lambda y: (y, y)
h = lambda x: (x, 'a')

print(f(g(h('x')))) # -> (('x', 'a'), ('x', 'a'))

# so simplified statement = lambda x: (xa)(xa)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a visual review of code translation; this is out of scope for Stack Overflow, and may even go beyond the Code Review group.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: It is incorrect. The result of `(λz.z) (λy.y y) (λx.x a)` is `a a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we'll translate each lambda -

- `(λz.z)` becomes `lambda z: z`
- `(λy.y y)` becomes `lambda y: y(y)`
- `(λx.x a)` becomes `lambda x: x(a)`

Next we'll evaluate the expression in entirety. `===` highlights substitution that takes place on each step -

```py
# (λz.z) (λy.y y) (λx.x a)
(lambda z: z) (lambda y: y(y)) (lambda x: x(a))
              ================     /     
          ___________/            /
         /                       /
(lambda z: z)          _________/
           =          /
     _____/          /
    /               /       
(lambda y: y(y)) (lambda x: x(a))
                 ================
         ________________/
        /
(lambda y: y(y)) 
           = =
    ______/   \______
   /                 \
(lambda x: x(a))((lambda x: x(a)))
                 ================
         _______________/
        /
(lambda x: x(a))
           =  \
     _____/    \
    /           \
(lambda x: x(a))(a)
                 =
         _______/
        /
(lambda x: x(a))
           = /
   _______/ /
  / _______/
 / /
a(a)
```